# django writing custom context processor

Tags: python, django

I'm writing my own custom `context_processor` on django (1.11) and to get infos of an authenticated user from auth0. It's not my first time writing it and I don't understand where this error comes from :

> ImportError : Module "auth.context_processors" does not define a "auth0_processors" attribute/class

Here's what it looks like :

**auth/settings.py :**

```
'context_processors': [
     'django.template.context_processors.debug',
     'django.template.context_processors.request',
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
     'auth.context_processors.auth0_processors', 
],
```

**auth/context_processors/auth0_processors.py :**

```
def auth0_user(request):
    try:
        user = request.session['profile']
    except Exception as e:
        user = None

    return {'auth0_user': user}
```

**accounts/views.py :**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Any idea?

Comment: The code you've shown wouldn't produce that error. That would happen if you had `'auth.context_processors.auth0_processors.py'` in your settings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, reloaded the page, updated error

Comment: I think you should probably rename your app to something other than "auth".

Comment: Did you remember to include `__init__.py` on sub folders?

Comment: @DanielRoseman renamed didn't change anything.

Comment: @danihp Yes I did include it

Comment: It should be `auth.context_processors.auth0_processors.auth0_user`.

Comment: You would have to append `'.auth0_user'` to the setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
'auth.context_processors.auth0_processors'
```

give the concrete method:

```
'auth.context_processors.auth0_processors.auth0_user'
```

At least that is what the error is complaining about:

> does not define a "auth0_processors" **attribute/class**

It is looking for a class or attribute, so try with the function name.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext):

> The **context_processors** option is a list of callables – called **context processors** – that take a request object as their argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the context.

In answer to your comment:

If you always need the same objects then just create one method that adds all of the required objects to the context instead of several methods.

EDIT:

Also note that with `'django.template.context_processors.request'` you could already have the complete `request` object in the context. You might not need your own context processor if you just need access to the session.

Comment: Does it mean I have to precise each function to the context_processors? Is there a way I can precise a file and import all the functions ?

Comment: No, but you can use a single function to return all of the context objects in one dict. I would create separate functions for different use cases - but if you would always need all of the objects in the context just use a single function?

Comment: Thanks, for the precisions!