# How can I avoid repeating same code block in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have the same code block in four of my functions. Is there a way that can avoid repeating the same code block?

Here is the same code block:

```
def function_name():
    # ...some code...
    hot_news_48h = h_mostViewed(48, News, '-pv')
    hot_news_1w = w_mostViewed(1, News, '-pv')
    # ...some code...

return render(request, "template_name.html", {
        #  ...some code...
        'hot_news_48h': hot_news_48h,
        'hot_news_1w': hot_news_1w,

        # ...some code...

    })
```

Here is function1:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))
    News.objects.filter(id=news_pk).update(pv=F('pv') + 1)

    hot_news_48h = h_mostViewed(48, News, '-pv')
    hot_news_1w = w_mostViewed(1, News, '-pv')

    relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag__id__in=news.tag.all()).exclude(id=news_pk)[:6]

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'news': news,
        'tags': tags,

        'hot_news_48h': hot_news_48h,
        'hot_news_1w': hot_news_1w,

        'relative_news': relative_news
    })
```

Here is function2:

```
def tagNewsList(request, tag_pk):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, pk=tag_pk)
    news_list = News.objects.filter(tag=tag)

    hot_news_48h = h_mostViewed(48, News, '-pv')
    hot_news_1w = w_mostViewed(1, News, '-pv')

    return render(request, "tags_list.html", {
        'news_list': news_list,
        'tag': tag,

        'hot_news_48h': hot_news_48h,
        'hot_news_1w': hot_news_1w,

    })
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Do you want to avoid repeating that block of code or something else? why do you want to merge them? If you need them in templates, you can send them via a context processor once and they will be available

Comment: Since `hot_news_48h` and `hot_news_1w` are nowhere affiliated to none of the views posted, they don't use any variables from views, it will be better to go with [`context_processors`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48020797/5644965)

Comment: Yes,I want to avoid repeating.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion:I finally solved the issue by using {% include news_rank.html %} + context_processors.It saves me a lot of code.Thank you for your direction.I learned one more thing today!Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In Django, you have the option to construct the response by employing a custom function that accepts relevant information as arguments. This function can then assemble the final response by incorporating any repetitive code blocks you wish to include. Below is a basic framework illustrating how you can implement this approach.

1. Create a file: Define a function that modifies the response.
2. Import the function into the views file of Django and invoke it within the desired function.

Here's an example implementation:

```py
# custom_response.py

def makeResponse(request, html_name, data_dict, News):
    data_dict['hot_news_48h'] = h_mostViewed(48, News, '-pv')
    data_dict['hot_news_1w'] = w_mostViewed(1, News, '-pv')
    return render(request, html_name, data_dict)
```

Next import the function into the views file of Django and invoke it within the desired function.

```py
# Views file
from 'utils.custom_response' import makeResponse

# function 1
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))
    News.objects.filter(id=news_pk).update(pv=F('pv') + 1)

    relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag__id__in=news.tag.all()).exclude(id=news_pk)[:6]

    return makeResponse(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'news': news,
        'tags': tags,
        'relative_news': relative_news
    }, News)


# function 2
def tagNewsList(request, tag_pk):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, pk=tag_pk)
    news_list = News.objects.filter(tag=tag)

    hot_news_48h = h_mostViewed(48, News, '-pv')
    hot_news_1w = w_mostViewed(1, News, '-pv')


    return makeResponse(request, "tags_list.html", {
        'news_list': news_list,
        'tag': tag,
    }, News)
```

Replace `'utils.custom_response'` with the appropriate import path to your function.

You can add this kind of feature to the post as well.

**If you want to set this for most of your API then it is better to set in the Django middleware.**

In Django, you can modify the response using middleware by implementing a middleware class that intercepts the response and adds your desired code. Here's a general outline of how you can achieve this:

1. Create a middleware class: Define a middleware class with a `process_response` method that modifies the response.
2. Register the middleware: Add your middleware class to the `MIDDLEWARE` setting in your Django project's settings file.

Here's an example implementation:

```py
# custom_middleware.py

class CustomMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to execute before the view is called
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # Code to execute after the view is called
        return response

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # Add your code to modify the response here
        response["X-My-Header"] = "My Custom Value"
        return response
```

In this example, the `process_response` method is used to modify the response. It adds a custom header "X-My-Header" to the response.

Next, register your middleware in the Django settings:

```py
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Other middleware classes...
    'myapp.custom_middleware.CustomMiddleware',
]
```

Replace `'myapp.custom_middleware.CustomMiddleware'` with the appropriate import path to your middleware class.

After adding your middleware, Django will automatically invoke its `process_response` method for each response generated by your views, allowing you to modify the response as needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy